# mysqlimport file not found error in Windows but exists a file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem with (Oh, I am using Windows 7, MariaDB 10.1.7)

```
mysqlimport -u root -p --fields-terminated-by="," --local db_name textfile.csv;
```

which founds an `ERROR 29, FILE 'C:\nodejs\textfile.csv;' not found <Errcode: 2 "NO such file or directory">`, when using table: btest

When I delete `'--local'`, it gives me a same error but still existing right path and there is a file!

But I have a existing file on that path. (That path is correct)
I want to know why `mysql` cannot find my file.

Is it a permission problem or anything else?
How can I grant permission to mysql?

(But on `CMD.exe`, when I write textfile.csv on the path, it opens.)

Answer (score -1):

Try installing PHPMyAdmin & importing using the GUI.  Might give you a few more options.  Also, check the first few lines of the exported db. If you are trying to import into a new db, make sure the sql file isn't trying to create a new db.